# Cannot access App Engine settings in new developers console

Tags: google-app-engine

When I log in to the Google Developers Console (console.developers.google.com) I cannot access the "Compute -> App Engine" settings page referenced in the documentation (https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/domain).  Only "Compute Engine", "Container Engine", and "Click to Deploy" are listed under "Compute".

The old console (Application Settings on appengine.google.com) has a popup link "try the new settings page" that links to the new settings page.  When I click on the link, it brings up the new developers console and then shows "Failed to load" in the middle of the page.

Can anybody else get to "Compute > App Engine"?

I'm only a user of Google App Engine.  I have not registered for Google Apps or Google Cloud Platform.

Answer (score 0):

Try to do a cloud integration in app engine settings page:

[image]